# Dataframe NA conversion to specific items

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data frame like;

```
dataframe <- data.frame(ID1=c(NA,2,3,1,NA,2),ID2=c(1,2,3,1,2,2))
```

Now I want to convert the NA value to the valuable which is the same to the next column valuable like;

```
dataframe <- data.frame(ID1=c(1,2,3,1,2,2),ID2=c(1,2,3,1,2,2))
```

I think I should use the `if` function, but I want use `%>%` for simplification.
Please teach me.

Comment: `dataframe$ID1[is.na(dataframe$ID1)] <- dataframe$ID2[is.na(dataframe$ID1)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward solution is to find out `NA` values in `ID1` and replace them with corresponding values from `ID2`.

```
inds <- is.na(dataframe$ID1)
dataframe$ID1[inds] <- dataframe$ID2[inds]
```

However, since you want a solution with pipes you can use `coalesce` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe %>%  mutate(ID1 = coalesce(ID1, ID2))

#  ID1 ID2
#1   1   1
#2   2   2
#3   3   3
#4   1   1
#5   2   2
#6   2   2
```

Answer (score 1):

An `ifelse` solution

```
dataframe <- within(dataframe, ID1 <- ifelse(is.na(ID1),ID2,ID1))
```

such that

```
> dataframe
  ID1 ID2
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   1   1
5   2   2
6   2   2
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` (using `%>%`) solution:

```
sanitized <- dataframe %>% 
  mutate(ID1 = ifelse(is.na(ID1), ID2, ID1))
```